# finding unique rows of a pandas Dataframe column for which all the values of a second column are NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Hi I am struggling with the following problem:

given a dataframe with columns `name` and `variable` I would like to create 2 lists:

- list_names_nan containing the names for which all the values in the variable column are nan
- list_names_not_nan containing the names for which at list 1 value in the variable column is not nan

below an example

```
import pandas
import numpy

df = pandas.DataFrame(data=[['x',1],['y',2],['x',4],['z',numpy.nan],
                            ['x',numpy.nan],['y',3],['x',numpy.nan],['z',numpy.nan],],
                            columns=['name','variable'])
df:
  name  variable
0    x       1.0
1    y       2.0
2    x       4.0
3    z       NaN
4    x       NaN
5    y       3.0
6    x       NaN
7    z       NaN
```

the desired output should be

```
list_names_nan = [z]
list_names_not_nan = [x,y]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) to create a boolean mask then use [`Series.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on this mask and aggregate using `all` finally use this mask `m` to filter the `nan` and `not_nan` values:

```
m = df['variable'].isna().groupby(df['name']).all()
nan, not_nan = m[m].index.tolist(),  m[~m].index.tolist()
```

Result:

```
['z']  # nan
['x', 'y'] # not_nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way using a custom aggregation function:

```
agg = df.groupby('name').agg(lambda x: all(np.isnan(x))).reset_index()
```

This generates an aggregated dataframe:

```
  name  variable
0    x     False
1    y     False
2    z      True
```

Then you can just get the names that are `False` or `True`

```
list_names_nan = agg.loc[agg['variable']==True]['name'].tolist()
list_names_not_nan = agg.loc[agg['variable']==False]['name'].tolist()
```